# How to save a pyspark sql DataFrame in xml format

Tags: xml, python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have stored a pyspark sql dataframe in parquet format. Now I want to save it as xml format also. How can I do this? Solution for directly saving the pyspark sql dataframe in xml or converting the parquet to xml anything will work for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but this package could be helpful. [Data Bricks Spark-XML](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#conversion-from-dataframe-to-xml)

Here is the example code for Python:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='book').load('books.xml')
df.select("author", "_id").write \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
    .options(rowTag='book', rootTag='books') \
    .save('newbooks.xml')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can map each row to a string with xml separators, then save as text file

Comment: I'd recommend a built in library like the Data Bricks Spark-XML example from @jmm312